# Only allowing input after x amount of time

Tags: timer

I've been given a problem to solve -

When the input is high (sensor), a timer should start which outputs high for 10 minutes (camera active). After 30 minutes, if the input is high, the process should being over.

I've learned about ripple counters to solve the start of the problem which is to output high for 10 minutes once the input is high

[image]

But I'm having trouble solving the other part. What I want to do is stop the input going in to the timer for 30 minutes.

The only way I can think to solve this is to break the connection between the input and the timer, and then re-connect it after 30 minutes using a switch.

[image]

Something instinctual just tells me that this is bad, and isn't the correct way.

Any help or just areas to look into would be great - Thanks

Comment: How about ANDing the input with your 30 minute timer? What hardware are you able to use for this? Because a ripple counter with a 10 minute output is either going to be a lot of bits or a really slow clock.

Comment: Is there any reason you are using a digital counter?  If timing doesn't have to be precise, a 556 (dual 555) would work.  Or you could also do this with an 8-bit microcontroller like the P10 or PIC16.

Comment: @Samuel If I AND the input with the timer, what would happen the very first time the input is high? The 30 minute timer would never be high so the 10 minute timer would never be high either. I can use anything I presume, my lecturer just mentioned ripple counters so I assumed that's what he's expecting.

Comment: If you have timers, you must also have a clock. Build a state machine.